# Adding an uneditable suffix to a SwiftUI TextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a TextField in SwiftUI that I would like to always display a "%" suffix on. The user should not be able to remove it and it should always remain on the righthand side, even when text is added.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **%** can be a separate view that always appears at exactly the correct position.

Wrap a UIKit control in `UIViewRepresentable`. This will give you access to more positioning information. If you wrap a `UITextInput`, then you can get the `CGRect` of the last character of text with [`firstRect(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614570-firstrect).

You can then display the **%** either:

- with UIKit in your custom view
- or add a callback or binding to your custom view that passes back the `CGRect` and display the **%** with SwiftUI.

If you want to display the **%** with SwiftUI, it can be achieved with a ZStack:

```
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
  Text("%").offset(x: lastCharacterPosition.maxX, y: lastCharacterPosition.minY)
  CustomTextInput(
    text: $text,
    onLastCharacterPositionChange: { rect in
      self.lastCharacterPosition = rect
    }
  )
}
```

Note in this scenario, `CustomTextInput` would have to be configured to be transparent. Also the offset might need some tweaking, I didn't try it out.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI-only: You can create **an invisible text under the textfield** with the same text, then add any suffix you want after that.

[image]

The gray input label below has an invisible `hidden()` text as a background, which always pushes the `Text("]")` text to the right place.

```
HStack(spacing: 1) {
    Text("[")
        .font(.sourceSans(size: 24, weight: .regular))
        .foregroundColor(UI.Color.foreground.secondary)
    TextField(
        mode.name,
        text: $word.phonemes.updating($lastUpdated)
    )
    .disableAutocorrection(true)
    .font(.sourceSans(size: 24, weight: .regular))
    .foregroundColor(UI.Color.foreground.secondary)
    .background(
        HStack(spacing: 1) {
            Text(word.phonemes)
                .font(.sourceSans(size: 24, weight: .regular))
                .hidden()
            Text("]")
                .font(.sourceSans(size: 24, weight: .regular))
                .foregroundColor(UI.Color.foreground.secondary)
            Spacer()
        }
    )
    Spacer()
}
.frame(height: 24)
```